# How to set gzip encoding with Node.js and socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Currently I have node.js set up, and I can communicate with my clients. But, I'm having trouble setting up gzip encoding to send my JavaScript files to the client.

I'm using node.js (version 0.7.3) with sockets.io (version 1.1.0).

I could not find any information on how to set this up; is this even possible?

Comment: Hopefully you're not using websockets to send javascript files, so that not very relevant. What would be relevant is what you've tried, and if you've tried any of the many many modules availabe for compression ?

Comment: Also, it should be noted that most of the time in production you want nginx or some other fast server that handles the static files and compression without ever hitting Node.

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean how to use Socket.io with gzip?

```
io.enable('browser client gzip');          // gzip the file
```

[Source](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/wiki/configuring-socket.io)

---

If you are asking how to use gzip outside of the socket.io communication as well, then answer depends on how you use Node.js:

1. Are we talking about the website?
2. Do you use any intermediate server like *nginx*?
3. Do you use any framework, for example *express*?

Comment: This is not supported after v1.0